# got this error : An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: appium-ios

Entered the desired capabilities from appium desktop and started the seesion and got this error : "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Answer (score 3):

On SetUp should be ("platformName", "iOS")

```
public void StartDriver()
 {
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
  cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Xr");
  cap.SetCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
  cap.SetCapability("app","YourApp.app");
  cap.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
  driver = new IOSDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));

   Assert.IsNotNull(driver.Context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could provide more information about your error, but guessing from the error text, this is caused when you do not provide `platformName` capability.